# CBCentralManager -- willRestore -- CBCentralManagerRestoredStateScanServicesKey

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

When restoring state with CBCentralManager the dictionary sometimes contains a scanned peripheral's UUID

```
internal func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, willRestoreState dict: [String : Any]) {
    let scannedPeripherals = dict[CBCentralManagerRestoredStateScanServicesKey] as? [CBUUID]
}
```

In contrast to *willRestoreState*, *didDiscoverPeripheral* provides CBPeripheral objects that the Central Manager can connect with.

My question is, what can I do with the UUID? The Central Manager can't connect or detect the device when this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the peripheral has already been discovered you don't need to scan for it.

You can pass the identifier to [`retrievePeripherals(withIdentifiers):`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanager/1519127-retrieveperipherals) in order to obtain a `CBPeripheral` instance that you can connect to.